# Why does my Python Script fail to connect to Discord?

Tags: python, ssl, discord, bots

I have written a Python script that essentially scrapes a website and sends a summary to a Discord channel via webhooks. All good. This script runs every half hour and sleeps in between. What I want to do though is activate the notifications via someone typing (say) "Start" in that Discord channel, and stop them via someone typing "Stop" - at which point I would go "silent" until another "Start" is detected. What I *think* I need to do is instantiate a Discord client in my script like so:

```
client = discord.Client()
client.run(CHANNEL_WEBHOOK_TOKEN)
```

and trap incoming messages like so:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Start or Stop processing
    return
```

However, I get an exception on the .run of:
Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True

I have seen plenty of comments about installing certificates but that won't work as my script is running in Heroku. I get the same error locally,and on PythonAnywhere too.

Am I taking the right approach? Or have I got it completely wrong and I need to make a Bot hosted on Discord as an app which sends my script stuff.

Comment: 2 things, client.run should be at the end for all of my knowledge, and just to make sure, did you create a bot inside the application and use the token from there?

Comment: You cannot run a discord bot on pythonanywhere since it does not allow websocket connections. Heroku might have the same limitation too, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I did not create a bot inside Discord, no. Hence my last sentence wondering if I was on the wrong path. So You are saying that I must do that and my script communicates with that ? So the discord bot is the client? What tasks should the bot do?

Comment: I think Websocket connections are allowed in PythonAnywhere in the paid version